# Optimizing PostgreSQL Query - Removing subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

I have the following query to get the value of a particular column : `level1` at the starting time and ending time. I'm currently using subqueries to perform this, but would like to just complete it with a single `SELECT` query.

```sql
SELECT
    id,
    (SELECT
         b1.level1
     FROM
         table b1
     WHERE
        b1.id = b.id 
        and b1.start_time = MIN(b.start_time)) AS level1_at_start,
    (SELECT
         b1.level1
     FROM
         table b1
     WHERE
         b1.id = b.id 
     and b1.end_time = MAX(b.end_time)) AS level1_at_end
FROM
    table b
GROUP BY b.id
;
```

SQL Fiddle link : [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/29194/1/0)

Sample input and output :

```
id    level1   start_time    end_time
-------------------------------------
i1    10     2              7
i1    50     5              10
i2    60     6              11
i2    20     1              6
i3    30     3              8
i3    40     4              9


id       level1_at_start   level1_at_end
----------------------------------------
i1       10                 50
i2       20                 60
i3       30                 40
```

Comment: Sample data would be helpful.

Comment: And, what did you try? Dit it work?

Comment: @MaciejLos Hey man, I've updated my question with sample input and output tables. Thanks.

Comment: SQL fiddle link : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/29194/1/0

Comment: These are `scalar subqueries`. Try to avoid them; they complicate your code.

Comment: @Marko: this works in this case because it's the WHERE clause of a scalar sub-query

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yeah you're right, I missed that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS) to extract values from within (differently ordered) groups:

---

```
CREATE TABLE ztable
        ( id text
        , level integer
        , start_time integer
        , end_time integer
        );

INSERT INTO ztable(id, level, start_time, end_time) VALUES
  ('i1', 10, 2, 7)
, ('i1', 50, 5, 10)
, ('i2', 60, 6, 11)
, ('i2', 20, 1,  6)
, ('i3', 30, 3,  8)
, ('i3', 40, 4,  9)
        ;

SELECT *
FROM    (
        SELECT id
        , first_value(level) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY start_time ASC ) AS first_level
        , first_value(level) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY end_time DESC) AS last_level
        , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY id ) AS rn
        FROM ztable
        ) zzz
WHERE zzz.rn = 1
        ;
```

---

Output:

---

```
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 6
 id | first_level | last_level | rn 
----+-------------+------------+----
 i1 |          10 |         50 |  1
 i2 |          20 |         60 |  1
 i3 |          30 |         40 |  1
(3 rows)
```

Comment: Thanks @wildplasser, this works. But is it not possible to just implement this with a single SELECT query, like without the subquery.

Comment: Yes. I only added the outer query because I needed the row_number(). Could be done with DISTINCT ON(), too. (I don't think there will be any difference in performance)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and windowing functions is really useful. Forgot to accept it!